# "Linq" отсутствует в пространстве имен "System"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net, linq

*"Имя типа или пространства имен "Linq" отсутствует в пространстве имен "System" (пропущена ссылка на сборку?)"* такую ошибку мне стала выдавать vs 2010 в Add-references добавлял core и linq но не помогло,подскажите,что делать

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего у вас проект под .NET 2.0. `System.Linq` появился в .NET 3.5.

Проверить версию .NET можно кликнув по проекту правой кнопкой в Solution Explorer  и выбрав Properties - там будет дропдаун Target Framework.

Comment: ,в том то и дело что это недавно появилось,в этом проекте,ничего не менял,А как проверить под какую версию проект

Comment: Правой кнопкой по проекту в Solution Exporer/Properties - там будет дропдаун Target Framework.

Comment: Target Framework 4,0 у меня

Comment: Тогда должно хватить референса на System.Core (C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Core.dll). Попробуйте перебилдовать все, и приведите полную ошибку компиляции в вопросе.

Comment: Через debug-Build web site ?

Comment: Build / Rebuild Solution

Comment: Везде пишет Имя типа или пространства имен "Linq" отсутствует в пространстве имен "System" (пропущена ссылка на сборку?)

Comment: Значит действительно пропущена ссыла на сборку в том проекте, на котором студия ругается при билде. проверяйте референсы. если проявилось недавно - откатывайте последние изменения.

Comment: Я создал новый проект и туда все перенес,все заработало.Спасибо!